# Cannot search nulls in multiple tables using a procedure with SQL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was trying to improve the scope of a large query I was doing. So to do this, I carried out a procedure so that my query would have fewer characteristics than it has.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE checknulls (tableyear TEXT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN

SELECT
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE regiao IS null) AS regiao_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE estado IS null) AS estado_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE municipio IS null) AS municipio_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE revenda IS null) AS revenda_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cnpj IS null) AS cnpj_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE nomerua IS null) AS nomerua_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE numerorua IS null) AS numeroruanull,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE complemento IS null) AS complemento_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE bairro IS null) AS bairro_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE cep IS null) AS cep_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE produto IS null) AS produto_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE datadacoleta IS null) AS datadacoleta_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE valordevenda IS null) AS valordevenda_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE valordecompra IS null) AS valordecompra_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE unidadedemedida IS null) AS unidadedemedida_null,
    COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE bandeira IS null) AS bandeira_null

FROM tableyear;

END; 
$$;

CALL checknulls(ca_2004_01);
```

I was able to create the procedure but when executing the CALL statement i was getting the error SQL state: 42703.
Anyone knows whats the problem?

I tryed to give all privileges for my user in postgres and making the parameter looks like 'ca_2004_01'::TEXT but its still doesn't work.
I want to define in the parameter of my procedure what table i want to get from the FROM statement.

Comment: then you need to read about dynamic sql in PostgreSQL